# Using memcpy and malloc resulting in corrupted data stream

Tags: objective-c, ios, c

The code below attempts to save a data stream to a file using fwrite.  The first example using malloc works but with the second example the data stream is %70 corrupted.  Can someone explain to me why the second example is corrupted and how I can remedy it?

```
short int fwBuffer[1000000];
// short int *fwBuffer[1000000];
unsigned long fwSize[1000000];

// Not Working *********

if (dataFlow) {
       size =  sizeof(short int)*length*inchannels;
        short int tmpbuffer[length*inchannels];
        int count = 0;
        for (count = 0; count < length*inchannels; count++)
        {
            tmpbuffer[count] = (short int) (inbuffer[count]);
        }

        memcpy(&fwBuffer[saveBufferCount], tmpbuffer, sizeof(tmpbuffer));
        fwSize[saveBufferCount] = size;

        saveBufferCount++;
        totalSize += size;
    }
// Working ***********

if (dataFlow) { 
    size =  sizeof(short int)*length*inchannels;
    short int *tmpbuffer = (short int*)malloc(size);

    int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < length*inchannels; count++)
    {
        tmpbuffer[count] = (short int) (inbuffer[count]); 
    }

    fwBuffer[saveBufferCount] = tmpbuffer;
    fwSize[saveBufferCount] = size;

    saveBufferCount++;
    totalSize += size;
}


// Write to file ***********

    for (int i = 0; i < saveBufferCount; i++) {
        if (isRecording && outFile != NULL) { 
  //        fwrite(fwBuffer[i], 1, fwSize[i],outFile);
            fwrite(&fwBuffer[i], 1, fwSize[i],outFile);
            if (fwBuffer[i] != NULL) {
  //           free(fwBuffer[i]);
            }
            fwBuffer[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You tried to get this code debugged yesterday in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919377/malloc-free-in-this-code-crashing-why#comment14241485_10919377) question.  I assure you memcpy and malloc are not the cause of your problem.  Recommend you rewrite the code and reduce the size of the problem rather than just posting the same question over and over under different guises.

Comment: I wonder why people totally ignore C++ while coding for MacOS/iOS... Yes, Objective-C and C++ are not quite "friends", but managing a memory at low level is much easier with STL. For instance, in your code you are "inventing a wheel" very similar to the std::vector.

Comment: Wadesworld, That was a different problem (same project) related to threads that has been corrected, but thx.  Also memcpy was nowhere in the other post.

Comment: Ok, start asserting your code.  In your loops, assert count < size.  Assert saveBufferCount < fwBuffer and fwSize array sizes.  Alos, make sure you free your new mallocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize your `size` as

```
size = sizeof(short int) * length * inchannels;
```

then you declare an array of size

```
short int tmpbuffer[size];
```

This is already highly suspect. Why did you include `sizeof(short int)` into the size and then declare an array of `short int` elements with that size? The byte size of your array in this case is

```
sizeof(short int) * sizeof(short int) * length * inchannels
```

i.e. the `sizeof(short int)` is factored in twice.

Later you initialize only `length * inchannels` elements of the array, which is not entire array, for the reasons described above. But the `memcpy` that follows still copies the entire array

```
memcpy(&fwBuffer[saveBufferCount], &tmpbuffer, sizeof (tmpbuffer));
```

(Tail portion of the copied data is garbage). I'd suspect that you are copying `sizeof(short int)` times more data than was intended. The recipient memory overflows and gets corrupted.

The version based on `malloc` does not suffer from this problem since `malloc`-ed memory size is specified in bytes, not in `short int`-s.

If you want to simulate the `malloc` behavior in the upper version of the code, you need to declare your `tmpbuffer` as an array of `char` elements, not of `short int` elements.

Comment: I was able to make progress with your help.  Above is updated code but I'm still getting some corruption.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user1440367: I don't see any relevant changes in your code. The problem I described is still there.

Comment: I applied your suggestions to the code above. It seems like everything is initialized properly.

Answer (score 1):

This has very good chances to crash

```
short int tmpbuffer[(short int)(size)];
```

first size could be too big, but then truncating it and having whatever size results of that is probably not what you want.

*Edit:* Try to write the whole code without a single cast. Only then the compiler has a chance to tell you if there is something wrong.